# SSMS Import MS Access 2016 Database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to convert a MS Access 2016 (.accdb) file to a SQL backend via SSMS (15.0.1835830). I have tried following the process descibed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160794/easiest-way-to-import-access-db-accdb-into-sql-server-2016) but was unable to get the option to import newer Access formats to appear.

I have found a way to export from Access to SQL Server, but that does not include table Relations as far as I am able to tell...

Does anyone know of a way to get an Access 2016 database into a SQL server?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck, specifally? The Import Wizard works "fine" from my experience.

Comment: Just as described, I cannot get the Import wizard option that allows MS Access files of the .accdb format to load. that being the "Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider" option.

Comment: So when you try to load the file, what error(s) do you get?

Comment: I cannot load the file as the only option I have is " Microsoft Access (Microsoft Jet Database Engine)" which only allows .mdb files. I have tried saving my .accdb as an .mdb but cannot do so...

Comment: You want the ACE drivers, not the Jet drivers. Jet is for Office 2003 and prior.

Comment: exactly, that is what the link in the thread linked should provide... which did not solve my problem....

Comment: So, again, *"Where are you getting stuck, specifically?"* We've "fixed" the problem where you were using the wrong driver, so now what is the problem..?

Comment: the problem is perfectly described in my first response. the option to load the .accdb file is not available to me, thus baring me from loading the .accdb file into ssms.... ssms cannot recognize my file. ssms will not process my file. ssms is not able to import my file. that is my problem.... is there another solution? is the driver provided by the thread the incorrect driver (note I am using 64 bit)?

Comment: So you are saying that you can't chose the ACE drivers? Then they aren't installed. Install the Ace drivers... You haven't explained *where* you are getting stuck, you are just saying "It doesn't let you." It's like calling a Mechanic to ask them how to fix your car, and when they ask "What is the problem." your response is "It's not working."

Comment: I'm working with a corporate computer and had our IT install it (even watched them do it), so I'm sure that the driver was installed... but still don't have the option. even in the thread provided someone else had a similar problem, but provided a solution I do not have the capability of using....

Comment: So where are you seeing that you "don't" have the option? Screenshots are actually going to be helpful here.

Comment: following the steps provided [here](https://help.avalara.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions/Rate_Files_FAQ/How_do_I_import_MS_Access_database_into_a_SQL_Server_database%3F), step 8 is where I should choose ""Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider" which should be available after installing the driver discussed. 

That option is not present. this is my problem, the solution provided on stackexchange is not working for me and I am looking for other solutions....

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, sounds like you haven't got the driver installed. You said you've installed the 64bit driver, so are you using the 64 bit import wizard?

Comment: ok, that is a new piece of the puzzle... how do I distinguish which import wizard I am using? I assumed that I  would do the same thing as before, right click the database > Tasks > Import data in ssms.

Comment: That would be the 32-bit client, as SSMS is only available in 32-bit

Comment: and this is where I get to slap my forehead... thank you for pointing that out.... where would I access the 64bit import wizard?